# Authenticate routes NodeJS Android app

Tags: android, node.js, session, authentication, routes

I am developing an Android app and I am having difficulty figuring out how can I authenticate routes on the server side, when the Android app makes a POST request.

For example, after logging in, if I go to a route that displays the profile of the user, I should be able to send back the session token and the store the user details into `req.user` for further processing like querying the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set something in `req` it will exist, for **the current** request.
It won't exist for any subsequent request.

In a mobile / api scenario you should send a token to the device during login, and the device send it back to you for every authenticated request. Take a look at [jwt](https://auth0.com/docs/jwt) for more on token expiration, format, etc.. it's the actual standard on authentication for mobile app.

If you are on a web / backend scenario in nodejs where you want to store user information in memory (like you seems to), or having a very lightweight cache, you could store it on the express `app`, or node `global` but that's just not scalable, as it would force you to make your server sticky to scale horizontaly (and also node app crash in case of uncaught error, you want to be agnostic to any restart of your app), so don't do that, it's awfull. You should use something like [memcached](https://memcached.org/) (also look at this [tutorial](http://iwearshorts.com/blog/nodejs-and-memcached-installation/)) to store the data.